# Source code review and analysys tools for Appcelerator Titanium or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

Is there any Source code review and analysys tools for Appcelerator Titanium or JavaScript ?
I can see some automated review tools like Checkstyle is available for Java. Is there anything similar for Titanium or JavaScript?

I tried with https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium-code-processor

But it shows error

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object. (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.14/lib/node_modules/titanium-code-processor/bin/codeprocessor:19:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Comment: Yes Got it working <br>Followed all the 4 steps without a mistake and 
1) [sudo] npm install -g titanium-code-processor
2) titanium config paths.commands --append /path/to/titanium-code-processor/commands
3) titanium config paths.hooks --append /path/to/titanium-code-processor/hooks

Note: On *NIX systems, the code processor is typically installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium-code-processor

4) titanium analyze -p iphone -A

Answer (score 0):

The Titanium Code Processor is now build into the Appcelerator CLI.

`appc ti analyze`

Comment: It seems to be a neglected feature.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Studio has also provided the `code analyser` tool. Just right click on the project and you can see the `code analysis` menu.

[image]